# What is the value of the integral $\int_c \frac{3z^2+z}{z^2-1}$? using residue theorem.

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-numbers

$$\oint_c \frac{3z^2+z}{z^2-1}$$
$$C:|z|=2$$
please ignore that the integration has to be circular integral. this the question provided, the following question has to be solved using the Cautchy Residue Theorem.

The following was done,
$$z^2-1=(z+1)(z-1)$$
the factors were determined and the poles are found out,
According to the given condition, both the poles are there in the circle given for circular integration

residue for $z=1$
$$\lim_{z\to1} \frac{(z-1)(3z^2-z)}{(z-1)(z+1)}=1$$
residue for $z=-1$
$$\lim_{z\to-1}\frac{(z+1)(3z^2-z)}{(z-1)(z+1)}=-1$$
so according to the Cautchy integral theorem the 
integral is $2\pi i\sum\operatorname{Res}\left(f,\ x_k\right)$
the integral answer is comming out to be zero. but the answer given in the book. is :$-4\pi i$

Comment: MathJax hint: `\to` or `\rightarrow`

Comment: You sure you wrote the problem correctly?

Comment: @V You have both $3z^2+z\;$ and $\;3x^2-z\;$ ...which one is it?! I took + as that's what appear in the title.and also in the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Cauchy's Integral Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_formula) after taking two little circles $\;C_1,C_2\;$ around $\;-1,1\;$ resp, say of radius $\;0.001\;$ (in the positive direction:

$$\oint_C\frac{3z^2+z}{z^2-1}dz=\oint_{C_1}\frac{\frac{3z^2+z}{z-1}}{z+1}dz+\oint_{C_2}\frac{\frac{3z^2+z}{z+1}}{z-1}dz=2\pi i\left(\left.\frac{3z^2+z}{z-1}\right|_{z=-1}+\left.\frac{3z^2+z}{z+1}\right|_{z=1}\right)=$$ .

$$=2\pi i\left(-1+2\right)=2\pi i$$

Comment: I did not know that was also a way to solve this question. Thanks man. I the answer given in the book is wrong.

Comment: My bad I made a mistake. as well

Answer (score 1):

Actually, we have

$$\lim_{z\to-1}\frac{3z^2+z}{z-1}=\frac{3-1}{-1-1}=-\frac22=-1$$

$$\lim_{z\to1}\frac{3z^2+z}{z+1}=\frac42=2$$

So,

$$\oint_C\frac{3z^2+z}{z^2-1}dz=2\pi i(-1+2)=2\pi i\ne-4\pi i$$

Comment: You have both $\;3z^2-z\;$ and $\;3z^2+z\;$ ...the OP seems to have confused both signs.

Comment: @DonAntonio I just found out.  :/